# Strange behaviour of edittext when receiving focus

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext, focus, android-softkeyboard

I have 2 layouts with EditText widget in them. In the first one EditText automatically receives focus on activity's start but shows no software keyboard (this is the desired behaviour). In the second layout, however, EditText is focused **and** shows soft-keyboard. I examined both layouts and can't find a reason for this behavour, because both widgets have identical properties. Soft-keyboard should only be displayed when I touch the input field. Am I missing something?

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/scanLine"
        android:layout_width="253.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19.0dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Comment: Hi, by `In the second layout, however, EditText is focused and shows soft-keyboard`, if you don't touch it, it can't get focused and show the soft-keyboard. By `Soft-keyboard should only be displayed when I touch the input field.`, yes, but if you don't touch the second layout, how can the EditText get focused? So, I think showing the soft-keyboard is normal. Maybe I didn't get your meaning. Do you want the soft-keyboard to dismiss when your second EditText gets the focused?

Comment: EditText is highlighted in blue and shows cursor without touching it. Doesn't that mean it has focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to the `onCreate()` method of your activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it helped!